# pip version is upgraded but not for current python version

Tags: python, pip, python-3.11

I am having an issue. I have installed Python version 3.11.3, it is current python version on my code editor at the moment. But, cannot install packages by *"pip install <...>"* command because when I check pip version I get:

```
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\emirh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

As you see, **python is not 3.11.3 version above.** Also checked system path but couldn't achieve a solution from there too. Already using *python -m pip install <package-name>* but I am expecting to see:

```
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\emirh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Information is bit lacking, Can you please add the current version details of `pip` and `python` on your machine and which system you are using (assuming its Windows).

> Check versions with `pip -V`, `python -V`
>
> Also, add output for `where python` and `where pip` for windows machine.
>
> If you want single line cmdlet you can try this on windows cmd prompt:
>
> `python -c "import os, sys; print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))"` this will gives you the path where python is stored.

Moreover, just to clarify with the solution, I'm using MAC and I hit the same issue as mentioned above to prevent this issue the major blocker is just to set the correct env paths.

For MAC users, we can upgrade the `pip` and `python` and then go for setting up the `$PATH`. Brew python changed it's location again and we had to update  **~/.zshrc** to:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/python@3/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Similarly for Windows Users, we can verify the env paths and map to the correct values.

Additionally, check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLjf35rOn9g) might help.